# Where is WSDL file located in SOA platform

Tags: architecture, wsdl, soa

I studied that `SOA` platform has three actors service `Provider`, `Consumer` and `Broker`. I also know that Service Provider publishes `WSDL` file to `UDDI` registry at `Broker`. `Consumer` discover the service by querying the `Broker`. But here i have a confusion. Does that mean that `WSDL` file is located on `Broker` and `Provider` both? and if yes then which `WSDL` file is used for binding `Consumer` with `Provider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of this articles is talking about exactly your question:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-wsdl/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-wsdl2/

> Universal Description Discovery and Integration (UDDI) provides a
>   method for publishing and finding service descriptions. The UDDI data
>   entities provide support for defining both business and service
>   information. The service description information defined in WSDL is
>   **complementary** to the information found in a UDDI registry. UDDI
>   provides support for many different types of service descriptions. As
>   a result, **UDDI has no direct support for WSDL** or any other service
>   description mechanism.

There are different scenarios  for publishing and finding complete WSDL service descriptions in a UDDI Registry (it depends on which WSDL service description combination of a service interface and a service implementation):

- Scenario 1: Service interface without a service implementation
- Scenario 2: Service implementation with one service interface document
- Scenario 3: Service implementation with multiple service
  interface documents
- Scenario 4: A single WSDL document
- Scenario 5: A
  service interface that references another service interface